# Climber starts at the top of cliff, finding fastest way to get down. (Optimization calculus)

Tags: calculus, optimization

> The starting point is 60m horizontally from the end point of the
>   climb.
>
> The first part of the route is 160m from the starting point but
>   contains flat rocks, and the climber can't climb very fast down
>   (40m/h).
>
> The second part of the course (65m) is a much better climbing surface
>   and the climber can climb down at a rate of (122m/h).
>
> Help the climber to find the fastest way down the cliff.

Without factoring in the differences in speed you would just use Pythagoras to get $$d(x) = \sqrt{(160m+65m)^2  + 60m^2}$$

However my best attempt to try and form an equation to derive and find the critical points is $$d(x) = \sqrt{60^2 + \left(\frac{160x}{40} + \frac{65x}{122}\right)^2}$$

Which doesn't seem right. Any help would be much appreciated.

[Optimization Sketch to better explain the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRO2H.png)

Comment: Could you draw a figure of this to clarify?  "the first part of the route is 160m from the starting point" describes a *point*, not a region.  Please clarify!

Comment: Sure, sorry if it isn't very clear. Hopefully this masterpiece brewed up in MS.Paint can explain the problem a little better. https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRO2H.png

Comment: I'm not a rock climber, but it seems to me that the assumption that climbing speed does not depend on direction is rather dubious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$T = t_1 + t_2 = \frac{\sqrt{160^2 + h^2}}{40} + \frac{\sqrt{65^2 + (60-h)^2}}{112}$$

Take derivative of $T$ with respect to $h$, set to zero to find optimizing $h$.

Answer:  $h = 26.52 m,$ measured from the top.

(If you're clever, you could use Snell's Law!)

---

Your error was in just computing the *distance*.  Instead, you are to minimize *time*, and the total time consists of two portions.  The *sum* of these two times must be minimized.

Comment: Awesome, thank-you!

Comment: +1 for Snellius; was my first thought.